# MVC Validating data

Tags: java, model-view-controller

I want to use MVC in my new project with Swing.

But I have some question.

In my `MainView` I have one input form and a submit button.
When I click on submit, my `MainController.setUrl(Value)` is called.
Then I have to verify the data. 
Where I must verify this data in my `MainController` ? in my `MainModel` ?
Or in my `MainController` I call a method like `MainModel.isValidUrl(Value)` ?

And if the data is wrong I want to display a dialog box to the user. So how can I call a method in the view to display this box?

Comment: This looks like a job for jQuery. Have you looked at using it in your project?

Comment: I'm using Java and Swing, not JavaScript. Moreover I'm not really fan about verifying data with JavaScript ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call your `MainModel.isValid` in your `MainController`, and from there show a dialog or persist the form (based on whether is valid or not). The `MainModel` should be responsible for its own validation.

When you instantiate your `Controller` from your `View`, just pass an instance of the `View` to your `Controller`.

The pseudo code would be something like this:

```
...
// In your view 
private void initTabPane(){
    AbstractModel socialModel = new SocialModel();

    // Pass the View
    AbstractController socialController = new MainController(socialModel, this); 
    ...
}


// In your controller
private AbstractView view;

public MainController(AbstractModel model, AbstracView view) {   
     ...
     this.view = view;
}

public Validate() {
    if (!model.isValid) {
        view.showError();
    }
    else {
        // do your stuff with the valid model 
    }
}
```

Comment: So `MainModel.isValid` is not a Boolean function but a void no ? And how work the notification with pattern Observer ? I've to notify only what changed, or when the View is notified, the view call the model to see what changed ?

Comment: It is still a `Boolean`. If it returns `false` then you return to your `View` and set an error dialog there. Or you can call a method on the `View` from your `Controller`, like `View.showError("Input form is invalid. Please correct the errors");`.

Comment: So in this way I must pass the View to my Controller and i'm not using the Observer pattern right ?

Comment: Well, usually you should have a handle on the `View` from your `Controller`. If you post part of your code and interactions I could probably better assist you.

Comment: I put all my code here : https://github.com/guitoun3/SeoToolBox/tree/master/SeoToolBox/src